# How to a custom "metabox" for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

**Background:**

Firstly, I'm unsure if this is even called a "[metabox](http://vvcap.net/db/aDvFTZVdYLEBcSbJoqjT.htp)"

Here's an example of how I "[use that metabox](http://vvcap.net/db/ZQ2_sa34oiogT7kjRLou.htp)".  As you can see `the_content()` method calls that metabox and sets the content.

**Full the_content HTML/PHP:**

```
    <section class="main">
  <div id="overview">
    <header> <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/brain.png"  />
      <h1>Ideas</h1>
    </header>
    <p>
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

All of this is held in a custom-post-type called **[custom_type](http://vvcap.net/db/u7Cf4ortsbVJdbdi4w0B.htp)**

**Problems:**

I only have access to ONE "[metabox](http://vvcap.net/db/ixEAb4BWoDjFVKEfJUMR.htp)" in custom_type.  I have 5 more boxes that need "metaboxs."  Does anyone have any idea on how to accomplish this?  Or any leads for tutorials that I can watch to learn from?  I'm having troble finding anything because I dont even know wtf this box is called!  Thank you so much!

Comment: I do believe the widget-like elements around the post area are indeed called metaboxes.

Comment: what is the post area called tho?

Comment: That I have no idea. Maybe it's just the post area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer: I found a great plugin called "custom-field-template."  The plugin to wordpress give custom-field creations a great interface.  Super easy to setup! and there is even a tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3VXnryN9iY whala